# CSS cover with heights in pixels and percentages

Tags: css, height, cover

I'd like to have a page with a first div with a 100% height (no problem for this), and two divs inside that cover the whole height of the parent div. If the 2 divs had a height in percentage, there will be no problem but the fact is that I need to have one div in pixels (specific height) and one other in percentage (cover the rest).

Can I do it in CSS or should I use javascript? (I like to use only CSS when possible)

Html structure :

```
<html style="height: 100%;">
<head></head>
<body style="height: 100%;">
    <div style="height: 100%;">
        <div style="height: 40px;"></div>
        <div style="height: ???"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any answer.

Ecorce

Comment: Did you try to do this?  What happened?

Comment: Why don't you give height in percentage for all div's its easy to manage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For filling available space in parent div just use this

```
.parent
{
  position: relative;
}

.child
{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;    
  top: 40px;   /* can set accordingly"*/   
}
```

So try this  code

```
 <div class="parent">
        <div class="fixedChild"></div>
        <div class="dynamicChild">ss</div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
body,html
{
    height:100%;
}
.parent
{
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background-color:Black;
    position: relative;
}
.fixedChild
{
    height:40px;
    background-color:Green;
}
.dynamicChild
{
    background-color:Red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    bottom: 0;
    width:100%;
}
```

here is [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ma6s/)

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all, if you want them appear from top to bottom, you should use `float` property, and for second height you can use `calc(100% - 40px)` here is browser support for this property (http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).